# Rejecting Duplicates of Same Number

Tags: java

Here are the instructions for what I am supposed to be doing.

> Write a program that inputs a string that represents a binary number.
>   The string can contain only 0s and 1s and no other characters, not
>   even spaces.
>
> Validate that the entered number meets these requirements. If it does
>   not, display an error message. If it is a valid binary number,
>   determine the number of 1s that it contains. If it has exactly two 1s,
>   display "Accepted". Otherwise, display "Rejected".
>
> All input and output should be from the console. Here are some sample
>   inputs to test:
>
> abc 10102011 10101FF 0000 1111 (note the space in this test case) 
>   00000000 1111 01110000001 1000001

What I have so far is written here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
 class ValidateBinary1
 {

 public static void main(String args[])

 {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter a binary number: ");

   String binary = input.nextLine();


  boolean isCorrect = true;
  boolean notCorrect = false;



  for(int i = 0; i <= binary.length() - 1; i++)
   {

   if(binary.charAt(i) == '1')
   {
       isCorrect = true;
   }

   else if(binary.charAt(i) != '0' & binary.charAt(i) != '1')
   {
      isCorrect = false;
      System.out.println("Wrong input! Please enter a valid binary number");
   }



 }

 if(isCorrect)
   System.out.println("Accepted");
 else if(notCorrect)
   System.out.println("Rejected");

  }
 }
```

What can I write to have the program output the "rejected" line?

Comment: what's the error with your current code?

Comment: The bitwise operator `&` and the logical operator `&&` aren't the same.

Comment: Your logic is not also correct check my answer.

Comment: What I need it to do is (when I run the program) reject my input if I type more or less than two "1"s

Answer (score 1):

Try this ( you are using bitwise operator `&` instead of logical operator `&&`) but I dont think using && either is correct; you have to use bitwise or `||`. Also you are not check for the number of ones, the number of ones in the input string must be exactly 2 according to your problem description.

```
  public static void main(String args[]){

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter a binary number: ");

  String binary = input.nextLine();

  boolean isCorrect = true;
  short numberOfOnes = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i <= binary.length() - 1; i++)
   {

   if(binary.charAt(i) == '1')
   {
       numberOfOnes++;
   }

   else if(! (binary.charAt(i) == '0' || binary.charAt(i) == '1'))
   {
      isCorrect = false;
      System.out.println("Wrong input! Please enter a valid binary number");
      break;
   }



 }

 if(isCorrect && numberOfOnes == 2)
   System.out.println("Accepted");
 else 
   System.out.println("Rejected");

  }
```

Comment: This seems like it is along the right path. The problem I am having now is that it is rejecting it even if I only input two 1s

Comment: Also, I am having to use the && rather than the || because when I use the || it tells me that everything I input is in the wrong format.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a binary number: ");
    String binary = input.nextLine();
    boolean isCorrect = true;
    boolean isCountCorrect = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++) {
        if (binary.charAt(i) == '1' || binary.charAt(i) == '0') {
            continue;
        } else {
            isCorrect = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isCorrect == true) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++) {
            if (binary.charAt(i) == '1') {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count > 2) {
            isCountCorrect = false;
        }
    }
    if (isCorrect = true && isCountCorrect == true) {
        System.out.println("Approved");
    } else
        System.out.println("Rejected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go. I took one of the answers and used it to modify my code and came up with this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
 class ValidateBinary1
 {

 public static void main(String args[])

 {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter a binary number: ");

   String binary = input.nextLine();


  boolean isCorrect = true;
  short numberOfOnes = 0;



  for(int i = 0; i <= binary.length() - 1; i++)
   {

   if(binary.charAt(i) == '1')
   {
       numberOfOnes++;
   }

   else if(binary.charAt(i) != '0' && binary.charAt(i) != '1')
   {
      isCorrect = false;
      System.out.println("Wrong input! Please enter a valid binary number");
   }



 }

 if(isCorrect && numberOfOnes == 2)
   System.out.println("Accepted");
 else
   System.out.println("Rejected");

  }
 }
```

This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!